# MultiValueDictKeyError when I trying to post image

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

When I trying to add image from admin panel all OK, but when I trying to add image from site, I have this error: [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7lwp.png). When I trying to post Detail without image, I have the same problem. Before this wasn't.

views.py:

```
def new_detail(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            car = request.POST['car']
            author = request.user
            detail = request.POST['detail']
            price = request.POST['price']
            description = request.POST['description']
            image = request.FILES['images']
            detail = Detail(car = car, author = author, detail = detail, price = price, description = description, images = image)
            detail.save()
            return redirect('/new_detail/')
else:
    return redirect('/login/')
return render(request, 'shop/new_detail.html')
```

new_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class=".signin">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>Автомобіль: </h3>
                <select name="car">
                    <option selected>Audi A8 D2 3.3 TDI</option>
                    <option>Audi A8 D2 3.7</option>
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...  
                <h3>Ціна: </h3><textarea name="price"></textarea>
                <h3>Фотки: </h3><input type="image" name="images" />
                <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Опублікувати" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Detail(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
    'auth.User',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    car = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='details', null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.detail

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail
```

Comment: Try <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post"> Also files are not in request.POST but in request.FILES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your form tag in the template. See [the docs on file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) for more info.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Secondly, your view doesn't handle the case when data is missing from the form. Instead of doing `request.POST['detail']` you should be checking `if 'detail' in request.POST` or using `request.POST.get('detail')`.

However it would be very time consuming to check every field individually. You should look at [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) and [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), which can handle a lot of this for you.

```
from django import forms

class DetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ['car', 'author', 'detail', 'price', 'description', 'images']
```

Then your view will be something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def new_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            detail = form.save()
            return redirect('/new_detail/')
    else:
        form = DetailForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'shop/new_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

You can use the form to simplify your template as well:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) if you need more control in the template.